# Overlay a panel of levelplots for raster with levelplots for categorical variables

Tags: r, raster, lattice, r-sp, levelplot

I want to overlay images made by `levelplot()`. Overlaying a list of 16 trellis objects on each panel of the raster is a nightmare. I can overlay the maps individually using grid resources but I prefer the beauty of `levelplot()`. Let me make a reproducible code of how the maps are realised.

```
lapply(c("raster", "rasterVis", "RColorBrewer"), require, character.only = TRUE)  
# create a rasterbrick
my.brick <- vector("list", 16)
for(i in 1:16){
  my.brick[[i]] <- raster(xmn = 30, xmx = 42, ymn = -6, ymx = 6)
  values(my.brick[[i]]) <- runif(ncell(my.brick[[i]]), 1, 250)
}
my.brick <- stack(my.brick) # the rasterlayers

cols <- c("white", brewer.pal(9, "Reds")) # my colours
my.at <- seq(0, 250, 25)

p1 <- levelplot(my.brick, col.regions = cols, at = my.at) # plot the raster
coods <- vector("list", length = 16) # object to hold my point data
my.plots <- coods  # An empty list to hold trellis objects

for(i in 1:16){ # A loop to create the spatial points
  coods[[i]] <- data.frame(lat = runif(10, 30, 50), lon = runif(10, 0, 20), 
                           val = runif(10, 1, 250))
  attach(coods[[i]])  ## let the headers become R objects
  coordinates(coods[[i]]) <- ~ lon + lat # convert to a sp object.
  my.plots[[i]] <- levelplot(val ~ lon + lat, col.regions = cols, at = my.at, 
                             panel = panel.levelplot.points, cex = 1.3) + 
    layer(sp.points(coods[[i]], pch = 21, bg = "white", col = "black", 
                    lwd = 2, cex = 1.5)) # Plots. The layer is meant enhance 
                                         # the width of the symbol outline
}
```

How do I overlay the`my.plots` which is a list to the raster plot `p1`?
There seems to be a few answers about this on stack exchange but I didn't find them sufficient.

Comment: I don't really understand the title of your question. Is it correct?

Comment: Kindly feel free to adjust the title of this question to fit the bill. Thanks Oscar

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved with the solution posted in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31667823/964866): use `latticeExtra::layer` combined with `panel.number`. Moreover, I have modified your code to simplify the object creation process:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

## Create a RasterStack
r <- raster(xmn = 30, xmx = 42, ymn = -6, ymx = 6)
my.brick <- stack(lapply(1:16, FUN = function(i)
    init(r,
         fun = function(x) runif(x, min = 1, max = 250)
         )))

## Create a list of SpatialPoints
prj <- CRS(projection(r))
pts <- lapply(1:16, FUN = function(i)
{
    pt <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(runif(10, 30, 42),
                                       runif(10, -6, 6)),
                                 data.frame(val = runif(10, 1, 250)),
                                 proj4string = prj)
})                    



## Display the raster and the points
levelplot(my.brick) +
    layer(sp.points(pts[[panel.number()]],
                    pch = 21, bg = "white", col = "black", 
                    lwd = 2, cex = 1.5))
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer Oscar. However, I'd like to have the points depict information in their own right. sp.points() can do the job but, in my opinion (I stand corrected), limited to adding just a few attributes like size, color and perhaps symbol type. As an example, temperature of a place can be measured from satellite and from surface stations. The raster should depict satellite temperature while the points should show station temperature. Once the two are overlaid, they should have a similar color key. How can I overlay the two levelplots at once? Thanks.